# Configuration of access to aws services for salt-master/salt-minion

Tags: amazon-web-services, salt-stack, salt-cloud

I have created small study aws infrastructure to learn SaltStack. There are three ec2 instances already running. (Master and two Minions). One minion is iam-role-less, one minion has role that enables him to access ec2 and s3 actions. (Roles settings purely for testing purposes.)

What I am trying to discover is how to configure salt-master (or salt-minion?) **so it has access to aws services**. For now, I can access the second minion with SSH and using boto3 i have acess to the ec2 and ss3. But if I use boto_ec2 execution module from salt-master => salt-minion, access error occur. I know that there is */etc/salt/cloud.providers* and */etc/salt/cloud.profiles* configuration that should be used. Most examples I saw were expecting that salt-minions will be created by salt, so I am a bit confused how to do it with pre-existing instances.

So the question is: "What is the right and correct way to configure master and minions to be able to use boto_ec2 module (or any other) from salt-master and orchestrate minions. Where and how should AWS credentials (keys) be set? Which config files has to be modified/added, what commands has to be run? Instances are already up."

I have found this link: https://salt-cloud.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/aws.html but there are places, where it says:

```
"The following settings are always required for EC2:"

# Set the EC2 login data
my-ec2-config:
  id: HJGRYCILJLKJYG
  key: 'kdjgfsgm;woormgl/aserigjksjdhasdfgn'
  keyname: test
  securitygroup: quick-start
  private_key: /root/test.pem
  provider: ec2
```

But it is not said where this config should be. On master/minion? Which file?
And when I run the command:

```
# salt '*142*' boto_ec2.exists Master
: 'boto_ec2' __virtual__ returned False
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

it's not working.

Comment: potential vote down topics.

Comment: Describe the actual issue you face and what you have done so far. The question sounds like open-ended.

Comment: I have edited it a bit. I it open question as the problem is opened. I cant find info about configuration.

Comment: Still, it is a question that only understood by yourself.  
Are you intend to create EC2 instances from a salt master then put salt-minion into those instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bare in mind that cloud support are not integrated tightly inside saltstack.

**How to do it with pre-existing instances.**
Say you have 3 EC2 instances. S1 (salt master), M1 & M2 is where you want to deploy salt minion.

Method 1 : Install salt-cloud inside your salt master, use saltify method

```
# filename : /etc/cloud.providers.d/sality-driver.conf
aws-saltify:
  minion:
    master: <ip_address_of_your_salt_master> 
  driver: saltify    

# filename : /etc/cloud.profiles.d/salt-minion.conf
minion1: 
  ssh_host: <M1-ip>
  ssh_username: <your_aws_instance_user_name>
  key_filename: "<full private_key_file path use to connect to minion>"
  provider: aws-saltify

minion2: 
  ssh_host: <M2-ip>
  ssh_username: <your_aws_instance_user_name>
  key_filename: "<full private_key_file path use to connect to minion2>"
  provider: aws-saltify

# run the command to saltify those host

sudo salt-cloud saltify -p minion1 <minion1-host-name>
sudo salt-cloud saltify -p minion2 <minion2-host-name>
```

Finger-crossing if it works.

**Method 2 : Use salt-ssh  **

IMPORTANT NOTE : salt.state.boto_ec2 is not complete under 2015.8.8(March 2016). So you really cannot deploy salt-minion into those machine using boto_ec2, perhaps you may give boto_lc a try or wait for new features.

```
#Create a folder just for salt-ssh deployment
mkdir ~/saltme

# master file for salt-ssh  ~/saltme/master 
file_roots:
  base:
  # Replace the "~" with you $HOME full path.  
    - ~/saltme/master

#create a roster file ~/saltme/minion-roster
my-bare-M1: 
  host: <to-be-minion-1-host-ip-address>
  user: <ami-default >
  sudo: True

my-bare-M2: 
  host: <to-be-minion-2-host-ip-address>
  user: <ami-default >
  sudo: True

# create your top file   ~/saltme/top.sls
base:
  '*':
    - saltify-minion

# create the state file ~/saltme/saltify-minion.sls
salt-minion:
  pkg.installed


# Now , inside the ~/saltme , run this against each to-be-minion-ec2
salt-ssh --roster-file roster --config-dir $HOME/saltme  -i --priv saltminion-1.pem  'my-bare-M1'  state.highsatte

salt-ssh --roster-file roster --config-dir $HOME/saltme  -i --priv saltminion-1.pem  'my-bare-M2'  state.highsatte
#Now accept the salt-minion key 
sudo salt-key -A
```

Comment: There is method 3.  Add salt-minion into the salt-master, then use boto_lc.present, but I am not sure how the state identify existing EC2 instance.  I know salt-cloud use the Tag  name to identify the instance, but there is no clue about boto_lc.